# Change a tag, which I created

Tags: support, tags

I've created a tag (my first one!) for the new version of `concrete5` which is a complete new build and needs a different tag (IMO). Now I called it `concrete5 - 57`. I would like to change it to `concrete5 5.7`. How do I do that?

---

It's a duplicate, but what helped me finally is to delete the tags and recreate them, because they were just used in my two questions. Thx to sphanley

Comment: Does adding the version number convey any significance?  That is, is `concrete5 5.7` substantially different to `concrete5 5.6`?

Comment: Note that neither of those tag names you're considering particularly conform to the structure commonly used for other `product-versionnumber` tags.

Comment: @Makoto Yes it is! It's a complete rebuild based on Laravel

Comment: @sphanley I've read the question you mentioned. So could anyone change it, so it'll be conform, please? Its only 2 questions
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949776/using-file-objects-in-a-single-page-controller
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864930/dashboard-controller-view-in-concrete5-5-7

Comment: Yes, if the newly created tag is removed from any questions you added it to, it'll be cleaned up and you can just recreate the version you want.

Comment: @sphanley Thank you! I removed the tags (used 2 times this year) and created a new one `concrete5-5.7` correct?